# Python multiprocessing with importlib

Tags: python, postgresql, multiprocessing

I want to use multiprocessing for importing modules. In 'conf' variable I have large list of modules names. Function loads classes names from module and checks if tables for those classes are created, if don't - they will be created in the database.

```
import importlib
from mymodule import exceptions
from datetime import datetime
from multiprocessing import Process

def process_import(ormModule):
    print "importing ...", ormModule
    t1 = datetime.now()
    try:
        importlib.import_module(ormModule)
    except ImportError:
        exceptions.log("Unable to import ORM module %s", ormModule)
        failed.append(ormModule)
    except:
        exceptions.log("Exception while importing ORM module %s", ormModule)
        failed.append(ormModule)
    t2 = datetime.now()
    total = t2 - t1
    print "finished importing %s %s" % (ormModule, total.total_seconds())

def loadClasses(conf):

    for ormModule in conf:
        Process(target=process_import, args=(ormModule,)).start()
```

Some of the modules are importing fine, but some don't

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
 'select relname from pg_class c join pg_namespace n on n.oid=c.relnamespace where n.nspname=current_sch() and relname=%(name)s' {'name': u'document1'}
```

How can I fix this problem? I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Does it run correctly when importing without multiprocessing?

Comment: This is done just for table creation, right? modules imported in one process will not be available to use in a different process.

Comment: Yes, for table creation, without multiprocessing modules are imported correctly. Some of the modules from 'conf' list may include import of other modules from this list.

Comment: 1. Are you opening the connection to the server before loadClasses?  Each Process shoud open the connection by itself.  Try not to import sqlalchemy before opening the processes.  2. What OS are you using? multiprocessing implementations vary.